# Permutation with two array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, math

I have list of 100 First Name and 100 Surname.
I want use mix of all the combinations without repetition.
Do you have some math solutions for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You don't need permutations but combinations. Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is called "cartesian product", php man page on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php shows some implementations (in comments).

and here's yet another one:

```
function array_cartesian() {
    $_ = func_get_args();
    if(count($_) == 0)
        return array(array());
    $a = array_shift($_);
    $c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
    $r = array();
    foreach($a as $v)
        foreach($c as $p)
            $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
    return $r;
}

$cross = array_cartesian(
    array('A', 'B', 'C'),
    array('1', '2')
);

print_r($cross);
```